# Core Animation - How to calculate duration so that two lines of different length are drawn at the same rate

Tags: objective-c, core-animation

I have two lines at different lengths

Line1 -----

Line2 -------------

How can I calculate the animation duration for each line so that they both are drawn at the same speed.

At the moment, I have a set value for duration

```
line1.duration = 1;

line2.duration = 1;
```

Because of the different lengths, line1's animation is slower than line2.

How can I calculate the animation duration with a fixed speed?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention that line1 doesn't know line2's length as the lines are drawn in a loop. What i'm after is a constant velocity calculation / pixels per seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
line2.duration = lengthOfLine2 / lengthOfLine1 * line1.duration;
```

(substitute the appropriate values.)

Comment: Close, i've updated the question. Line1 doesn't know the length of line2

Comment: @totalitarian "as the lines are drawn in a loop" - then store the length of the previous/next line in a temporary variable. Make some effort yourself, please.

Comment: Sorry but do I really need to store anything? Two cars travelling at the same speed don't need to know the distance the other one has to travel.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming: Drawing at same rate - You mean both of them should end drawing simultaneously.

Suppose Line 1 : Length - 100 px

Suppose Line 2 : Length - 350 px

Then suppose 1 px takes 1 ms then Line 1 will take 100 ms

For Line 2 to take 100 ms it needs to draw (350/100 = 3.5 px/ms)

So suppose Short line takes time "t" for line of length "l1"

Then greater line should take time "l2/t" for line of length "l2" 
for both of them to stop drawing simultaneously.

Comment: "You mean both of them should end drawing simultaneously." - No, that's what currently happens. Velocity != speed.

Comment: you can assume velocity=speed if they are drawn in the same direction

Comment: @H2CO3 absolutely they are not. I was just referring to velocity vs speed. +1 to your solution :)